# different results - scikit learn

Tags: scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer, average_precision_score, balanced_accuracy_score, f1_score
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

scoring1 = ['average_precision']
scores1 = cross_validate(model, X_train[selection], y_train, scoring=scoring1, cv=skf)['test_average_precision'].mean()
print("scores1 : ", scores1)

scoring2 = {'average_precision': make_scorer(average_precision_score)}
scores2 = cross_validate(model, X_train[selection], y_train, scoring=scoring2, cv=skf)['test_average_precision'].mean()
print("scores2 : ", scores2)

scoring3 = {'average_precision': 'average_precision'}
scores3 = cross_validate(model, X_train[selection], y_train, scoring=scoring3, cv=skf)['test_average_precision'].mean()
print("scores3 : ", scores3)

scores1 :  0.8458995430639721

scores2 :  0.7025850825147928

scores3 :  0.8458995430639721
```

Theses 3 functions should give the same result. Why it is not the same?

For information, Theses 3 functions give the same results when I use these metrics  :
"accuracy",
"precision",
"recall",
"f1",
"balanced_accuracy",

but not for "average_precision".

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

"Average precision" averages over possible decision thresholds, so you need to tell `make_scorer` to use soft predictions instead of hard class predictions.

Prior to sklearn version 1.4, you would set either `needs_proba=True` or `needs_threshold=True`; starting from 1.4, you should use `response_method="predict_proba"` or `response_method="decision_function"`.